Syntax Error line 0, col 70: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_INSTANCE, got '.'
I want to make a request to retrieve elements from my table that contain a property called 'stat.' This property is a discriminator. When I retrieve the elements based on the discriminator as in the following post https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/4462, I encounter the following error: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 70: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_INSTANCE, got '.'.
In the first part, you will find the annotation of the discriminator, and in the second part, the method of my repository.
/**
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "a" = "A",
 *     "b" = "B"
 * }) * 
**/
abstract class Stat implements JsonSerializable
{

    public function findWithFilter(array $params): array
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ftch');
        if (isset($params['networkType']) && count($params['networkType']) > 1) {
            $orX = $qb->expr()->orX();
            foreach ($params['networkType'] as $networkType) {
                if ($networkType === NetworkType::A->value) {
                    $orX->add($qb->expr()->isInstanceOf('ftch.stat', 'App\Entity\A'));
                } elseif ($networkType === NetworkType::B->value) {
                    $orX->add($qb->expr()->isInstanceOf('ftch.stat', 'App\Entity\B'));
                }
            }

            $qb->andWhere($orX);
        }
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }


To resolve this error, you just need to add the inner join ->innerjoin('ftch.stat', 'stat').
